# Bulk upload c# set the sheet of excel file

Tags: c#, bulkupdate

How to define the sheet of excel file that want to upload?
This is my sample code.

```
string Sheet_1 = Excel_Con
      .GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null)
      .Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"]
      .ToString();

using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter
      ("SELECT [Question_No] AS Question_No, " + 
       "[Question_Description] AS Question_Description, " + 
       "[Is_Option] AS Is_Option, " +
       "FROM [" + Sheet_1 + "]" +
       "WHERE Question_Description IS NOT NULL"
       , Excel_Con))   
{
    oda.Fill(ExcelData);
}
```